# 'Go to Definition' for events

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

I am using Visual Studio 2013.  If I have a method call like this:

```
CallMe();
```

I can right-click on it and choose 'Go to Definition' to see the body of this method.

But if I have an event like this:

```
Called(sender, new EventArgs());
```

right-clicking on this and choosing 'Go to Definition' will take me to the declaration of the event but not to the body.

How do I find the body for this event?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to recreate [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms229614(v=vs.100).aspx). Perhaps the reason the event is null is because you have no subscribers because they expect a actual `INotifyPropertyChanged` and not your re-implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An event does not have a "body" - an event has *subscribers* that are notified when the event occurs and execute an *event handler*.  By design, the event does not know who its subscribers are, nor is it required to have any subscribers.  So the entire definition of an event is contained in its declaration.

Visual Studio does not have built-in support for locating all subscribers of an event. The best you can do is use the "Find All References" command to locate every place a subscriber attaches to the event.

Comment: @dbnex14 If nothing has subscribed to the event, it will be null.  (An event is really just a wrapper around a multicast delegate, so if there are no subscribers, the delegate is null.)  It sounds to me like some additional reading on [delegates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx) and [events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/awbftdfh.aspx) might be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks @BJMyers.  I will do the reading and repost my update as separate question as you already answered my original question here.  Much appreciated.